# Replicate Flash Cube Rotation in CSS: Preserve correct perspective

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash, apache-flex

I am converting a Flash Web App to a Javascript(HTML and CSS) Web App. I have a cube rotation animation working but I have a problem with the perspective.

**My Problem:** I am not sure which CSS attribute I should use to replicate the Flash versions perspective(please see the 2 images below).

The 2 below images where taken while the cube rotation was occuring and you can see the difference in the perspective(the 2nd image is too wide and should look like the first). You can see a working example here(Note it only works on Chrome or Safari): http://jsfiddle.net/CyyZx/6/

- The first image was taken from the flash application and displays the CORRECT perspective(that I am trying to achieve in CSS).

[image]

- The 2nd image is taken from my CSS, Javascript and HTML web app and the cube rotates with the INCORRECT perspective. What CSS attribute do I change in order to achieve the above images cube perspective?

[image]

*Please note:* The cube faces have the exact same dimensions as the flash version. I currently use the CSS attributes -webkit-perspective: 0; -webkit-perspective-origin: 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `.cubeContainer` selector, you have `-webkit-perspective: 0;`, it should be `-webkit-perspective: 1000;`.

This will set the perspective 'further back' from the screen, where 0 sets the perspecitve to pretty much where the screen is.

http://jsfiddle.net/CyyZx/7/

Comment: thanks for the help :), why 1000 though, is it in relation to the width/height of each cube face/div? Can I always specify 1000 and it will work no matter how big the cube faces are?

Comment: It's really down to personal taste. I use 1000 as I think it's gives a nice look, you can use 100 but the box not "go so far back." Experiment with the number and see what you like. The faces will always be the same width/height you specify, so choose a perspective that works with that would be my advice :)